# Pass same data to multiple view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can you give me some pointers about load view in CI

```
$this->load->view('maindata', $data);
$this->load->view('footerdata', $data);
```

Is passing the same variable to multiple views is bad? Why?
That two view requires some of the same data

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/views.html)?

Comment: Of course. I just want to know is passing same variable is bad and why?

Comment: Where did you get the impression that it is bad?

Comment: Maybe because it pass other variable that not be used in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next syntax for such a requirement:

```
$this->load->vars($data);

$this->load->view('maindata');
$this->load->view('footerdata');
```

That way, `$data` array will be available to any loaded view. [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars).

Comment: data is available for all view, but it is showing data multiple times

Answer (score 1):

you can access $data variables like  title to maindata view and $footer_data to footerdata view .

```
$data['title'] = "Welcome";
$data['user_name'] = "John Doe";

$data['footer_text'] = "This is Footer";
$this->load->view('maindata', $data);

$this->load->view('footerdata', $data);
```

Comment: The question is passing same variable to multiple view

Comment: see updated code , you can access this three variable to this two of your views

Comment: This is correct, but you can also use `$this->load->vars()`.

Comment: The next question is. it is bad practice?how about the perforrmance? Why?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it isn't bad to pass the same data. However, there could be better options, see my example below for one idea.

When I set up my sites, I try to make the header and footer as generic as possible and then I load them from within the view. So, my view code looks like this:

Controller:

```
public function page() {
    ...
    $this->load->view('main', $data);
}
```

View (main.php):

```
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
<!-- HTML -->
<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

With this method, all of the data passed to the main view is defined in each of the 'sub-views', the header and footer.